# Is it possible to use Sequelize typescript in NodeJS without using sequelize-typescript framework?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a working solution for a sequelize-typescript implementation. No problem, but we have to use a database IBM DB2 (AS400). And we can't use sequelize-typescript because IBM DB2 interface doesn't support construct like this:

```
import { Table, Column, Model, HasMany, AllowNull } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export class Locatie extends Model<Locatie> {

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  locatie: string;
  .........
  ......... 
}
```

My first question is is it possible to use the typescript coding when using the 'sequelize' npm lib and the '@types/sequelize' ?
(It means we have to exclude  the  sequelize-typescript  framework )

In my code I can't get it running, this is my code for initialize the connection and start up database:
(The connection  to the mssql database is made without a prboblem but if I want to create a table then I get an error)

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import { Locatie } from '../model/locatie.model';

export class OrmDB {

sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1433,
    database: 'testabcd',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    username: 'sa',
    password: 'secret',
    storage: ':memory:',
    logging: false,
    define: {
      timestamps: false
    }
  });

initialize() {

    this.sequelize
      .authenticate()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection to database is ok');

        //create table: When I add this code block that throws an error like this:
        //    \node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:919... throw new Error('No Sequelize instance passed');
        Locatie.sync().then(() => {
          return Locatie.create({
            locatie: 'test',
            opmerking: 'verzin'
          });
        });
        //end create table
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database', err);
      });

    //this runs without a problem but table is not created.
    /*  this.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
       console.log(' It works, table Locatie is NOT created or synced ??');
     }); */

  }
}
```

And this is my model I tried to use the require and import which is commented out but nothing works.
(The name of the file is locatie.model.ts

```
//import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

//import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Model = Sequelize.Model;

export class Locatie extends Model{}

  Locatie.init({
    locatie: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    opmerking: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
   create_door: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    create_dat: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    wijz_door: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    wijz_dat: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    }
  },{ Sequelize, modelName: 'locatie'});
```

This is in my package.json:

```
"@types/sequelize": "^4.27.48",
"sequelize": "^5.7.6",
"ts-node": "^8.1.0",
"typescript": "^3.4.5"
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: I have added also the imports and class and connection parameters

Comment: Sequelize doesn't support DB2 dialect. Watch this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6263

Comment: Sequelize is supported by IBM DB2 AS400:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-ibmi. But the sequelize-typescript lib is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:
When I don't use the typescript-sequelize framework I have to use an other type of class. The sequelize-typescript framework uses anotations. That is not possible if it comes to the IBM DB2 sequelize connector:

Below is the class which I have to implement, I am realizing myself that this kind of code does not have much to do with the typescript standard:

```
import { Model, DataTypes, BuildOptions } from 'sequelize-ibmi';
import * as config from 'config';
import * as atob from 'atob';
import { LoggerSligro } from '../../api/utils/logger';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize-ibmi');

//IBM AS400  (let op gebruikersnaam in hoofdletters, ACS met ODBC moet geinstalleerd zijn inclusief sequalize-ibmi en odbc van npm lib)
 export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'ibmi',
    odbcConnectionString: 'DSN=SLIGRO20;UID=PITTENSB;PWD=bwnnlbs197',
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

export class Afdeling extends Model {
    public afdeling!: string;
    public groep1!: string;
}

Afdeling.init({
    afdeling: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    groep1: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
}, { sequelize});

export class Activiteit extends Model {
    public activiteit: string;
    public afdelingId: number;
}

Activiteit.init({
    activiteit: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    afdelingId : {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
       /*  references: {
            model: Afdeling,
            key: 'id'
          } */
    },
}, { sequelize});

Afdeling.hasMany(Activiteit, {foreignKey: 'afdelingId', sourceKey: 'id'});
Activiteit.belongsTo(Afdeling, {foreignKey: 'afdelingId', targetKey: 'id'});
```